# Render Image without background

Tags: rendering, transparency

I tracked a scene, and then successfully set up a tracking scene. I then added my mesh to the scene, but now when I render the sequence I still get the Video I tracked as the Background.

Generally, to render an image without the background you need to, in the "Scene" tab unselect the "transparency" option in the Film section, and select RGBA image as the output of the render.

This didn't work for me for some reason, so in the Camera Settings I removed all Background images, which in my case were only the video clip. In my outliner window there was an "object" (not really an object, just dont know what you call individual thins in the outliner window) called background, which I first deselected for the render, and then after seeing no change deleted completely.

I tried restarting Blender to see if that would change anything, but nothing happened.

When I render an image in the rendered window I can see the optioin to view the fore and background, which I can view separately, but when animationg a sequence Blender automatically merges them and saves them as one image. I thought of disabling this, but I don't know how to do that.

Does anyone know what to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error in the Compositing tab I figured out thatdisconnecting the movie clip from the render layer removed that clip, obviously, but the background then turned white, after which I connected both the Composite and Viewer Alpha channels to the Render Layer, after which the background dissapeared, just like I wanted.
[image]

So after rendering with the above node setup my result was just a white mesh without textures or any surface an a transparent background because the render window was somehow overlaying the fore and background. I then tried some other Node conection variations, until I ended up with this one:
[image]

This one got me the result I wanted, the mesh, alone and with a transparent background. I don't know what exactly happened, but this seems to do the job for me.